# How to add a function inside sum() in R language

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
SampleName <- c(A,A,A,A,B)
NumberofSample <- c(1,2,3,1,4)
SampleResult <- c(3,6,12,12,14)

Data <- data.frame(SampleName,NumberofSample,SampleResult)
head(Data)

SampleName NumberofSample SampleResult
1 A 1  3
2 A 2  6
3 A 3 12
4 A 1 12
4 B 4 14
```

My idea is: when SampleResult <15 && SampleResult >5, Sample A has 6 sample sites which match the condition, and Sample B has 4 sample sites which match it. So the ideal results would look like this:

```
SampleName Frequency
1 A 6
2 B 4
```

I write something like:

```
D1<- aggregate(SampleResult~SampleName, Data, function(x)sum(x<15 && x>5))
```

But I feel this lack something like

```
x * Data$NumberofSample[x]
```

So my question is what's the right way to code? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`.  Grouped by 'SampleName', subset the 'NumberofSample' that meets the condition based on 'SampleResult' and get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
     group_by(SampleName) %>% 
     summarise(Frequency = sum(NumberofSample[SampleResult < 15 & 
              SampleResult > 5]))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  SampleName Frequency
#  <chr>          <int>
#1 A                  6
#2 B                  4
```

---

If we prefer the `aggregate`

```
aggregate(cbind(Frequency = NumberofSample * (SampleResult < 15 & 
          SampleResult > 5)) ~ SampleName, Data, sum)
#   SampleName Frequency
#1          A         6
#2          B         4
```

---

Note that the output of `&&` is a single TRUE/FALSE value

```
(1:3 > 1) && (2:4 > 2)
```

instead of a logical vector of the same length

Answer (score 2):

akrun’s solution is spot-on. But it so happens that {dplyr} offers a convenience function for this kind of computation: `count`.

In its most common form it counts the number of rows in each group. However, it can also perform a *weighted* sum, and in your case we simply weight by whether the `SampleResult` is between your chosen bounds:

```
Data %>% count(
    SampleName,
    wt = NumberofSample[SampleResult > 5 & SampleResult < 15]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following form of `aggregate` is simpler. I subset `Data` based on the condition you want and then take the `length` of each group.

```
inx <- with(Data, 5 < SampleResult & SampleResult < 15)
aggregate(SampleResult ~ SampleName, Data[inx, ], length)
#SampleName SampleResult
#1          A            3
#2          B            1
```

Another possibility would be

```
subData <- subset(Data, 5 < SampleResult & SampleResult < 15)
aggregate(SampleResult ~ SampleName, subData, length)
```

but I think the logical index solution is better since its memory usage is smaller.